# How to find an object by name in pyqt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, objectname

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
globalParams = [{'attr':'enabled','ctrl':'checkBoxEnabled','type':'checkBox'},
                {'attr':'colorMode','ctrl':'comboBoxColorMode','type':'comboBox'}]
```

'ctrl' - name of the control in the Qt window.

typically, the code is as follows:

```
self.checkBoxEnabled.checkState()
```

but checkBoxEnabled is an object. and i have only a string name 'checkBoxEnabled' and cannot use it...

how to find an object by name in pyqt? something like?
self.***GetObjectByName('checkBoxEnabled')***.checkState()

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `QObject::findChild` method. In pyqt it should be written like this:

```
checkbox = self.findChild(QtGui.QCheckBox, "checkBoxEnabled")
```

`self` should be a parent widget of the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

To find all the QCheckBox items in your UI you can run a loop through all the children of the widget like as below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

class Mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # super().__init__()
        self.checkbox = QCheckBox(self)
        self.checkbox_1 = QCheckBox(self)

        for checkstate in self.findChildren(QCheckBox):
            print(f'get check state:{checkstate.checkState()}')
```