# PyQt: How to dynamically call objectNames?

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, pyqt

I created 9 QPushButtons which objectName's are E1, E2, E3, ..., E9.
Now, I want to update their text field with strings I get from a database, so I want to do something like this:

```
query="SELECT evento FROM eventos;"
cur.execute(query)

i=1
for fetch in cur:
    evento=str(fetch)
    objectname="E"+str(i)
    self.objectname.setText(evento)
    i+=1
```

This loops fetches 9 lines (9 strings) and updates the buttons' display text. The problem is that I have to tell it which button to update and I can't figure out how to do it dynamically since the lines: `objectname="E"+str(i)` and `self.objectname.setText(evento)` won't work because `AtributeError: 'MyWindowClass' object has no attribute 'objectname'`

Comment: You want `getattr()`

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: [How to find an object by name in pyqt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048657/how-to-find-an-object-by-name-in-pyqt)  You want to lookup objects depending on the *Qt name* you have set in their `objectName` property?

Comment: Yes germn! It works perfectly! Thank you so much! I could kiss you right now! Didn't know about this gettattr() function.

Comment: @DiogoMagalhães you're welcome :) Feel free to accept answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(self, "E"+str(i)).setText(evento)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
self.findChild(QtGui.QPushButton, 'E{0}'.format(i)).setText(evento)
```