# Find item in QApplication by only the objectname

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, teamspeak, pythonqt

i want to find any object by a objectname  string name inside of the QApplication

Something like

```
QApplication.instance().findByClassName("codeEditor")
```

which should return a list of widgets with this classname that i can iterate over if there is more then one

```
[QPushButton (QPushButton at: 0x0000008EA3B3DD80), QWidget (QWidget at: 0x0000008EA3F33F40)]
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048657/how-to-find-an-object-by-name-in-pyqt) but it requires a object and i want something like `*`

This is something i came up with for testing:

```
def findWidget(name):
    name = name.lower()
    widgets = self.topLevelWidgets()
    widgets = widgets + self.allWidgets()
    ret = dict()
    c = 0
    for x in widgets:
        c += 1
        if name in x.objectName.lower() or name in str(x.__class__).lower():
            ret["class:"+str(x.__class__)+str(c)] = "obj:"+x.objectName;continue
        if hasattr(x, "text"):
            if name in x.text.lower():
                ret["class:"+str(x.__class__)+str(c)] = "obj:"+x.objectName
    return ret
```

It doesn't even find the 'InfoFrame' which is clearly there:

```
>>> widget("info")
```

{}

[image]

Comment: since (almost) everything is derived from `QObject` look for that class type

Comment: @SebastianLange What do you mean?

Comment: @SebastianLange https://snag.gy/md8M7Y.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this which works quite well

```
def getWidgetByClassName(name):
    widgets = QApplication.instance().topLevelWidgets()
    widgets = widgets + QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
    for x in widgets:
        if name in str(x.__class__).replace("<class '","").replace("'>",""):
            return x
def getWidgetByObjectName(name):
    widgets = QApplication.instance().topLevelWidgets()
    widgets = widgets + QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
    for x in widgets:
        if str(x.objectName) == name:
            return x
def getObjects(name, cls=True):
    import gc
    objects = []
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if (isinstance(obj, PythonQt.private.QObject) and
            ((cls and obj.inherits(name)) or
             (not cls and obj.objectName() == name))):
            objects.append(obj)
    return objects
```

Comment: `allWidgets` necessarily includes `topLevelWidgets`. Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Neither of these functions work. For the first one, `str(x.__class__)` will return something like `"<class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget'>"`, so it's obviously never going to match. You need to use `x.__class__.__name__`, but even then, this won't match subclasses. For the second function, you need to use `str(x.objectName())`, otherwise it will never match anything. And note that both functions will only return the first object found, not a list of all matching objects (which is what the question asks for).

Comment: The changes you made do not fix any of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, this can be done for any class using the [gc module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#module-gc). It provides a method for retrieving the references of all objects tracked by the garbage-collector. This is obviously a quite inefficient approach, but it does (almost) guarantee that any type of object can be found.

Here's a function to get a list of all `QObject` instances either by class-name or object-name:

```
def getObjects(name, cls=True):
    objects = []
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if (isinstance(obj, QtCore.QObject) and
            ((cls and obj.inherits(name)) or
             (not cls and obj.objectName() == name))):
            objects.append(obj)
    return objects
```

This is only really a debugging tool, though - for a large application, there could easily be several hundred thousand objects to check.

If you only need objects which are subclasses of `QWidget`, use this function:

```
def getWidgets(name, cls=True):
    widgets = []
    for widget in QtGui.QApplication.allWidgets():
        if ((cls and widget.inherits(name)) or
            (not cls and widget.objectName() == name)):
            widgets.append(widget)
    return widgets
```

**PS**:

If you want to find all objects which are subclasses of `QObject`, this can only be achieved if you can somehow ensure that all the instances in your application have a valid parent (which, by definition, must also be a `QObject`). With that in place, you can then use `root_object.findChildren(QObject)` to get the full list. It is also possible to use [findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) or [findChildren](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) to search for individual objects by object-name (optionally using a regular-expression, if desirable).

Comment: This is a good approach but it doesn't work for me: http://i.imgur.com/HreomDd.png

Comment: @Bluscream. Why would you expect it to work if you don't create any `QObject` instances? You obviously have to run it in the same python interpreter where the objects were created.

Comment: But i want to search for existing objects, not the ones i've created, obviously...

Comment: @Bluscream. It makes no difference **who** created them. The objects either exist in the current python interpreter session, or they don't. If you want to know exactly which objects currently exist, just do `import gc; for x in gc.get_objects(): print(repr(x))` (warning: it could be a very long list).

Comment: This crashes the application >.<

Comment: @Bluscream. No, it's you that did that. I'm guessing you just copy-pasted it as one line, instead of putting `import gc` on it's own line. Please try to use a little bit of common sense.

Comment: I tried both and they are both causing the app to crash

Comment: @Bluscream. It all works perfectly fine for me. I guess your application must be buggy somehow, or perhaps some third party library you are using is buggy.

Comment: i think its because i only have 2gb ram

Comment: @Bluscream. I very much doubt that. Are you running this in an IDE of some kind? If so, that could cause problems. Create a very simple pyqt test script that just creates a few widgets, and try the two functions in my answer to check that they work okay. If they don't, you know it's a problem with the IDE.

Comment: @Bluscream. So you're using the pyTSon plugin, which I presume uses some kind of embedded python interpreter. I had a quick look at the forum, and the first thing I see is this: "**CAUTION** This is currently alpha software, so it can (and I guess, it will!) crash your client". Need I say more?

Comment: everything may crash teamspeak. It doesn't have any error handling

Comment: @Bluscream. I really think you should have made it clearer this was specifically about a third-party application in your question. I've tagged it with `teamspeak` now. I have to say I'm a bit peeved that I've wasted a lot of my time trying to help you with this.

Comment: its qt and python, why do you think your time was wasted?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to find all `QObject` instances in general. Qt does not keep track of them since objects can be used in multiple threads and the overhead of tracking them would be unnecessarily high.

Qt does keep track of all widgets, though, since widgets can only exist in the main thread, and they are fairly heavy objects so tracking them has comparably little overhead.

So, you could search all widgets you get from `QApp.allWidgets()`, and all of their children. You can also look through children of objects you otherwise have access to. But if a given object is parentless, or is not owned by a widget, then you won't find it that way.

Comment: I thought of some selector like if you want to search the dom in jquery `$('someElement')`

Comment: @Bluscream Yes. So? I thought of all sorts of things. Do you have a question, or a comment on this answer? Saying that you thought of something random doesn't help.

Comment: If you think you need a global object search, you're doing it wrong. Keep track of the objects you need: you have the best resources to do a good job. The framework will help you, but it won't do it for you since its design can't foresee your circumstances.

Comment: I'm doing nothing wrong, javascript has a global ui search, too which is something everyone uses quite often.

Comment: @Bluscream Qt has it too. For the Ui objects - i.e. `QWidget`s. And that's all that you can have, because only widgets live on one thread so searching all of them makes sense. From that thread.